# Sub domain install options

Tags: config

How can I setup sub domains on a single domain to allow development of multiple Craft client sites. I tried dev1.domain.com and dev2.domain.com and it tells me I need to upgrade license since I need the pro features. Sites are still on development. What is best naming convention?

Comment: I think I got it. Looks like dev-site.domain.com works.

Answer (score 2):

Have `staging` or `dev` in the name, as in `blah.dev.domain.com` or `blah.staging.domain.com`  It needs to be a full sub-domain, not a partial like you had in your example.